# Output on CSV and argument in powershell are not same

Tags: powershell, csv

I got user information from the user group in AD. every column has no problem except the user name.

On csv, User name is normal but there is a format when I get content from csv for using powershell like as below;

@{Name=abc}

for compare-object with two CSV, I need to use -expand.

Is there anyway to avoid this result?

I want to get a same content on CSV and powershell.

`get-adgroup $path -server server.com | get-adgroupmember -recursive | select-object -unique | get-aduser -properties mail | name, mail | export-csv c:\result.csv`

Comment: your code and your question doesn't seem to relate, also your code has syntactic errors. its not clear what CSV you're referring too. we can't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `import-csv` cmdlet to import the csv and not `get-content`. Also the provided code sample won't work - e.g. you missed `select-object` here:

```
 | name, mail |
```

You do not need to query the group, as you already know the name ($path), you can directly query the groupmemberships, e.g.:

```
get-adgroupmember -identity $path -recursive
```

But in the end you could achieve the same in a much more efficient way, e.g.:

```
get-aduser -LDAPFilter "(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=[groupDistinguishedName])" -property mail | select-object -property mail,name | export-csv [path]
```

replace [groupDistinguishedName] with the distinnguishedName of the group. This will give you all users back which are member (transitive) of the defined group.

see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/4e638665-f466-4597-93c4-12f2ebfabab5